# Can I use Navigation Drawer without ActionBar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Up to project requirements there should not be an ActionBar in the application, but I need to to use Navigation Drawer. Is it possible to use it without ActionBar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it should be possible. Programmatically call `getSupportActionBar().hide()`

Comment: You don't need to hide the ActionBar either.  You can use the NavigationDrawer without having an ActionBar at all.